# Sometimes, I don't get a ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have created my receiver and am listening for ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED. I have code that responds to the creation of the bond and moves forward with other things.

The problem is that about 2/3 of the time, I pair with the device and my code on ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED never gets called. One third of the time it does.

There's nothing in the log after my log entry that says that I'm waiting for the bonding.

Is there some other result that can happen as a result of a pair request?